# How can i get the doc inside doc from collection firebase?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

Hi !
How can i get the documents inside "ListaFavorite"?

I can get all other documents except this list , I only get [object object] , it need to pipe again the documents or i dont know.

Here is what i use:

**fav-page.html**

```
 <ion-col *ngFor="let fav of this.favItems | async">        
          <ion-card>
            {{ fav.ListaFavorite}}
          </ion-card>
</ion-col>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
async addFavorites(
    uniqID: string,
    favorite_title: string,
    favorite_description: string,
    favorite_image: string,
    favorite_tag: string,
    favorite_stoc: boolean,
    favorite_reducere: number,
    favorite_price: number,
    favorite_userId: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    this.MyUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const { uid } = this.MyUser;

    const favoriteObj = {};
    favoriteObj[uniqID] = {
      favorite_title: favorite_title,
      favorite_description: favorite_description,
      favorite_image: favorite_image,
      favorite_tag: favorite_tag,
      favorite_stoc: favorite_stoc,
      favorite_reducere: favorite_reducere,
      favorite_price: favorite_price,
      favorite_userId: favorite_userId,
      isFavorite: true,
    };

 this.favItems = this.firestore
      .collection<User>("users", (ref) => ref.where("uid", "==", `${uid}`))
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map((actions) =>
          actions.map((a) => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;

            return { id, ...data };
          })
        )
      );

}
```

This way i can get the uniqueID of the object so i can simple do:
 `console.log(this.favItems.ListaFavorite[uniqID].favorite_description);`

but i get this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'bayonete-QSrpS5021' of undefined`

The thing is.. i already have the product in firebase , but it can't find the fields?

What is the next step ? xd

Answer (score 1):

ListaFavorite is a map type field.  It contains other maps, **not** documents.  In your code, you should treat it like a normal JavaScript object with properties whose names are the what you see in the console.  You will need to know the names of the nested fields in that map in order to use them.  For example:

```
fav.ListaFavorite['bayonete-XXXX'].favorite_description
```

If you don't know the names in the map, you're going to have a hard time trying to figure out how to find the nested values.

Comment: Thanks for helping sir! I updated my question , still i can't get my desired fields even if i put the right id..

Comment: The error message is now telling you that `this.favItems.ListaFavorite` is undefined.  I don't think that `this.favItems` contains what you think it does.

Comment: I see. I tried this '  console.log(data.ListaFavorite[`bayonete162bcaca`].favorite_description); ` and i managed to get the field , but i used this inside the pipe function. I think im getting closer

Answer (score -1):

Hi i finally found a solution to my problem.
So basically , i just declared properties inside my function then i easy called them in html by the propery like this:

```
checkFavorite() {
    this.MyUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    const { uid } = this.MyUser;
    const data = this.MyUser.email;
    const myDoc = { uid };

   this.favItems = this.firestore
      .collection<User>("users", (ref) => ref.where("uid", "==", `${uid}`))
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map((actions) =>
          actions.map((a) => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;

            return {
              id: a.payload.doc.id,
              Title: a.payload.doc.data().ListaFavorite[`bayonete162bcaca`].favorite_title,
              Description: a.payload.doc.data().ListaFavorite[`bayonete162bcaca`].favorite_description,
            };
          })
        )
      );
  }
```

And in HTML:

```
  <ion-col size-lg="6" size-md="6" size-sm="6" size-xs="12" *ngFor="let fav of this.favItems | async">
          <ion-card>
            {{  fav.Title }}
          </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
```